# Can't login to my Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Its started from this morning. I don't know whats wrong here. When you first install chrome you enter your google account. Then it save all your datas like browse history, bookmarks etc right? I just use that normally. But from today I no longer can login. My login information is correct. But its just rejecting me after I logged in. Its like it's not saving my login session.

Screen recording: https://youtu.be/HUALuoVIWh0

Comment: What if you try logging in directly through the Google website?

Comment: I can. I currently logged into google site, and youtube etc.

Comment: Is this any help? https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/AJAstn8z1xY

Comment: It's not about websites. Its about Chrome itself. watch my video

Comment: The post is also about Chrome. I would imagine Chrome is almost certainly using cookies under the covers to manage this.